# SSH cannot connect to qemu ARM emulator

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, qemu

I have boot-up the armhf standard machine with ssh on port 22 from [here](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armhf/)
Using this command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-vexpress -initrd initrd.img-3.2.0-4-vexpress \
-drive if=sd,file=debian_wheezy_armhf_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

As explained in [this](https://gist.github.com/Liryna/10710751) tutorial I've set an ssh-server private/public key pair invoking `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on it.

Then when I to connect it from my guest machine Ubuntu 17.10 x64

```
ssh -p 5555 localhost
```

I get this error:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

When I try explicitly to ssh connect to the virtual machine invoking

```
qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 &
```

I get this message

> qemu-system-arm: -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22: Could not set up host forwarding rule 'tcp::5555-:22'

What is the problem ?

How can I ssh connect to the arm emulator ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you confirm that the `sshd` server is actually running on the virtual machine?

Comment: I think so. I have a working process called /user/sbin/sshd (with no children)

Comment: can you post the output of `ssh -vvv -p 5555 localhost` it will give more debugging information which might help track down the issue.

Comment: `OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 5555.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 5555: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 5555.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 5555: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 5555: Connection refused`

Sorry I can't ident the script output CTRL+K is hijacked by Firefox to focus the address line.

Answer (score 1):

you need to connect the qemu to the current terminal
add this to you running line

```
-append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0,115200 acpi=off nokaslrearlyprintk=serial,ttyS0,115200"
```

and then where you inside the qemu
configure the ip of your nic:

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.15 netmask 255.255.255.0 up && route add default gw 10.0.2.2
```